# I wrote "Bundle Identifier", but I have problems

Tags: unity-game-engine

error code:

> UnityException: Bundle Identifier has not been set up correctly
>   Please set the Bundle Identifier in the Player Settings. The value must follow the convention 'com.YourCompanyName.YourProductName' and can contain alphanumeric characters and underscore.
>   Each segment must not start with a numeric character or underscore.
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

My bundle Identifier is not "com.Companyname.ProductName".
Why does this problem happen?

Comment: What is your bundle name? The error is not saying it must be exactly that, but that it should follow the same structure. So something like com.yuki.yukisawesomegame

Comment: If Company Name written at the top of Player Settings is "A" and Product Name is "B", Bundle Identifier is "com.A.B".Or is there a problem in other places?

Comment: No spaces in there?

Comment: I confirmed, but there was no space.

Comment: Any chance you can share your actual settings with us? Take a screenshot? Don't know if it's sensitive somehow.

Comment: @Yuki any updates on this? this post can be useful for other people ;)

Comment: Do you think that this is a problem other than Package Name, Company Name and Product Name?
If so, where do you think the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the library file of the project file and restarting Unity was cured. Do not forget to backup!